# Non-recursive way to search an infinite list of vectors in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, vector

I've got a data structure like the following:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as V
mylist :: [V.Vector (Int, Int)]
```

I need to search through this list of vectors to look for an element satisfying a predicate. The algorithm guarantees that I'll find the element.

So far I've got something like this:

```
go []     = error "Could not find"
go pred (p:ps) =
  case V.find pred p of
    Just a  -> a
    Nothing -> go ps
```

It's simple, but I'd like to get rid of the recursion. Is there a construct that lets me "compose away" the recursion?

Comment: The [Hoogle results for `(a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> b`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+Maybe+b%29+-%3E+[a]+-%3E+b) are pretty suggestive.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that your function is itero-recursive or tail-recursive, meaning that it automatically will get turned into a loop rather than a stack recursion. With that said, what you've done can be expressed in many other ways, many of which hide the loop in existing constructs. For example, using `Data.Maybe.isJust` there is a point-free version, `go = (head .) . filter . (isJust .) . V.find` or, partially applied, `go p = head . filter (isJust . V.find p)`.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-0.2/docs/Control-Newtype.html) package, this can be conveniently written

```
import Control.Newtype
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Foldable

go :: Foldable f => (a -> Maybe b) -> f a -> Maybe b
go = ala' First foldMap
```

which I think nicely exposes the structure you are using in this computation.

Comment: For those who, like me, are confused by the magic `ala'` function, this is just `\f -> getFirst . F.foldMap (First . f)`.

Answer (score 2):

At some point recursion is used, but you could certainly simplify this using `Data.Monoid` and `map`:

```
go :: (a -> Bool) -> [V.Vector a] -> Maybe a
go pred = getFirst . mconcat . map (First . V.find pred)
```

I would recommend leaving this as returning `Maybe a` instead of using `error`, most will generally recommend against the use of `error` since it simply crashes your program instead of allowing you to exit gracefully.

Another way you could implement this is with `Data.Maybe` functions:

```
go pred = listToMaybe . catMaybes . map (V.find pred)
```

Or

```
go pred = listToMaybe . mapMaybe (V.find pred)
```

Or you can use the `MonadPlus` instance for `Maybe` (import `Control.Monad` first):

```
go pred = msum . map (V.find pred)
```

Or the `Alternative` instance in `Control.Applicative`:

```
go pred = foldr (<|>) empty . map (V.find pred)
-- Or using foldl if you really want to
```

There really are many ways to solve this problem.

Comment: `foldr (<|>) mzero` should probably be `foldr (<|>) empty` to avoid mixing `Alternative` and `MonadPlus`, which is then just `asum` -- essentially the same as `msum`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Good point, I mixed up which `:i` output I was looking at.